# how to stop my program from skipping characters before saving them

Tags: c, file-io

I am making a simple program to read from a file character by character, puts them into tmp and then puts tmp in input[i]. However, the program saves a character in tmp and then saves the next character in input[i]. How do I make it not skip that first character?

I've tried to read into input[i] right away but then I wasn't able to check for EOF flag.

```
FILE * file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
char tmp;
char input[5];
tmp= getc(file);
input[0]= tmp;
int i=0;
while((tmp != ' ') && (tmp != '\n') && (tmp != EOF)){
    tmp= getc(file);
    input[i]=tmp;
    length++;
    i++;
}
printf("%s",input);
```

It's supposed to print "ADD $02", but instead it prints "DD 02".

Comment: What is input? Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Change `int i=0;` to `int i=1;`. Also change `char tmp` to `int tmp`.

Comment: Read a char first. Then test whether to end the loop. In the loop, store the read char and as the last thing in the loop, read the next char, so that the loop condition uses the fresh input.

Comment: input is a character array:
char input[5];

Comment: Still no MCVE. Edit your question!

Comment: whenever i try to "store" the current character it stores the next one instead, so it reads and stores in one step

Comment: That's because you have the order of your operations mixed up. it's take a char, test it, process it, take the next char, but you take a char, test it, take the next char, process that, and so on ... (You can find out about such errors by stepping through your code, either in a debugger or with paper and pencil.)

Comment: Double check the size of the buffer. 5 is not enough to take the desired output of "ADD $02".

Comment: @MOehm can you please give an example code?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing things in the wrong order in your code: The way your code is structures, reading and storing the first char is moved out of the loop. In the loop, that char is then overwritten. In that case start with `i = 1`.

Perhaps you want to read the first character anyway, but I guess you want to read everything up to the first space, which might be the first character. Then do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char input[80];
    int i = 0;
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        if (i + 1 < sizeof(input)) {         // store char if the is room
            input[i++] = c;
        }

        c = getchar();
    }

    input[i] = '\0';                         // null-terminate input

    puts(input);

    return 0;
}
```

Things to note:

- The first character is read before the loop. the loop condition and the code that stores the char then use that char. Just before the end of the loop body, the next char is read, which will then be processed in the next iteration.
- You don't enforce that the char buffer `input` cannot be overwritten. This is dangerous, especially since your buffer is tiny.
- When you construct strings char by char, you should null-terminate it by placing an explicit `'\0'` at the end. You have to make sure that there is space for that terminator. Nearly all system functions like `puts` or `printf("%s", ...)` expect the string to be null-terminated.
- Make the result of `getchar` an `int`, so that you can distinguish between all valid character codes and the special value `EOF`.

The code above is useful if the first and subsequent calls to get the next item are different, for example when tokenizing a string with `strtok`. Here, you can also choose another approach:

```
    while (1) {                          // "infinite loop" 
        int c = getchar();               // read a char first thing in a loop

        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == EOF) break;
                                         // explicit break when done

        if (i + 1 < sizeof(input)) {
            input[i++] = c;
        }
    }
```

This approach has the logic of processing the chars in the loop body only, but you must wrap it in an infinite loop and then use the explicit `break`.

Comment: whenever i try to set bit 0 of input it goes crazy. Am i ever allowed to do that? like do input[0] = tmp;?

Comment: You mean byte? Sure, if you have `char input[5];` then 0 is a valid index for `input`.